# Try-Catch Macro in Julia

Tags: macros, julia

I have the following functions.

```
foo(x) = x + 1
bar(x) = x * 2
```

I use them in a wrapper function (not sure whether this is even important).

```
function baz(x)
    d = Dict{Symbol,Any}()
    d[:foo] = foo(x)
    d[:bar] = bar(x)
    return d
end
```

The problem is that `foo()` and `bar()` can fail, and I want the code to continue running in this case. Introducing `try catch` statements would make the code very messy, however. So, is there maybe one of the following two solutions out there, that could make this easier?

**Dream Solution**

A macro that I could just write in front of `d[:foo] = foo(x)` and which in case of failure would write a default value do `d[:foo]`.

**Also-a Solution**

A macro that would just continue if the code fails.

Comment: Perhaps something like [Try.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPreludes/Try.jl)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I managed to do the following. However, I have no clue if this is in any way good style.

```
macro tc(ex)
    quote
        try
            $(esc(ex))
        catch
            missing
        end
    end
end

@tc foo(1)
1

@tc foo("a")
missing
```

Note the `$(esc(ex))`. This is important. If the expression is not escaped, the macro will work as expected in the global scope but not inside a function (as in the question). If anyone can provide a crisp explanation of why this is the case, please add a comment.